# How to calculate the Mutual Information between a given term and class in R?

Tags: r, feature-selection, information-gain

Given an input file of `N` lines with the following format:

```
doc_id, class, text
```

the `class` field has two values only [0,1] (i.e., two classes)

the `text` field consists of a set of space-separated terms.

How can I use R to calculate the mutual information between each unique term in the dataset and each class.

Comment: Have you looked at this http://finzi.psych.upenn.edu/library/DescTools/html/Entropy.html?

Comment: Thanks. I assume I need to build a term-class matrix. Right? 
What would be the value? Frequency of a term occurring with a given class?

Comment: Check out the examples -- I can't help more than they do.